# IPython function arguments display

Tags: python, ipython, python-idle

I am using IPython 6.3.1 with Python 3.6.5 on an x86_64 Linux system.

I have been using IDLE for some time and was thinking about switching to IPython. I am used to seeing the parameters of a function which is shown in IDLE but this is not happening in IPython.

Example:

```
import math

math.pow(x, y)
```

In IDLE, as soon as "math.pow(" is typed, it shows the two expected parameters by the method. This is not happening in IPython.

Is there a way to 'turn it on'? I tried "Shift Tab" too, but nothing happens.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont get this option if you are using command line. If instead you use Jupyter Notebook or Jupyter Lab (based on IPython) you will get this feature by pressing TAB or SHIFT+TAB.

Comment: You are correct. I read about it and it turns out what you said. Thanks!